# ¿No veo mi proyecto local en github?

Tags: github

Tengo mi proyecto local pero al realizar los pasos para poder subirlo a github y veo mi trabajo en github.com no se visualiza mi repositorio, está vacio Que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

estos son los comandos que venian en el ejemplo

```
git init

git add .

git commit -m "first commit"

git remote add origin https://github.com/NOMBRE_USUARIO/NOMBRE_PROYECTO.git

git push -u origin master
```

Comment: El repo ya existe? ¿Te pregunta usuario y contraseña al hacer git push? ¿El comando `git status` te marca alguna modificación pendiente, como archivos nuevos?

Answer (score 2):

Inicia con el comando :

```
git init
```

despues usa este comando para ver el estado del git

```
git log
```

despues selecciona el proyecto(te sugiero que sea una carpeta la que subiras donde este el proyecto )

```
 git add Programador
```

despues con este comando vez el estado del proyecto

```
 git status
```

despues creas un commit y le agregas el comentario asi :

```
git commit "proyecto"
```

vuelves a ver el estado del git para confirmar que todo esta correcto con el comando

```
 git status
```

pero antes de nada agrega la informacion de login de tu github asi :

```
 git config --global user.name "user"
```

```
 git config --global user.email  "example6@gmail.com
```

seleccionas el repo (su nombre)

```
     git romote add Programador 
https://github.com/gilbertoquinteroA/proyectoprogramador.git
```

y con este comando lo mandas a tu repo en github

```
  git push remoto master
```

Y Listo , si tienes un problema comenta yigualmente puedes ver mas informacion en el help de github : 
[help github](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/)